# promise.all does not reject failed fetch requests

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

For example in:

```js
  const settingPromises = Object.keys(values).map(key => {
    return fetch(`${client}/settings`, {
      signal,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: _.kebabCase(key),
        value: values[key]
      })
    })
  })

  const settings = await Promise.all(settingPromises)
  const results = await Promise.all(settings.map(setting => setting.json()))
```

If one fetch fails, `console.log`ing `settings` returns something like:

```js
settings -- (2)[Response, Response]
[
  {
    type: 'cors',
    url: 'api.example/settings',
    redirected: false,
    status: 400,
    ok: false,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

...and `Promise.all` is successful, doesn't reject the Promise.

How can I make it reject when a request fails?

Comment: OT: please use `async` arrow function for readability :)

Comment: @DimaTisnek in which part?

Comment: Good point, technically you don't have to :D I was thinking `await Promise.all(Object.keys(xx).map(async k => {const r = await fetch(k); if (!r.ok) throw XX; return await r.json(); }))`. But you can also do: `const rs = await Promise.all(Object.keys(xx).map(fetch)); const good = rs.filter(r => r.ok); const results = await Promise.all(good.map(r => r.json()))`; whichever makes more sense for you -- imperative or functional programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fetch` won't reject its promise on failed requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch), so you have to append a handler, that decides whether the request was successful:

```js
const settingPromises = Object.keys(values).map(key => {
    return fetch(`${client}/settings`, {
      signal,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: _.kebabCase(key),
        value: values[key]
      })
    }).then(response => {
      if(response.ok) return response
      throw response
    })
  })

  const settings = await Promise.all(settingPromises)
  const results = await Promise.all(settings.map(setting => setting.json()))
```